# How to store Python/file data in memory until written to disk?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Python script that writes to disk every time it runs, which happens very frequently. It collects data that changes just as often so I cannot change the rate at which the script runs. I would like to reduce the number of disk writes by only writing after every x minutes. I need the different script results to persist in memory over multiple script runs. The result data consists of lines of text, which are all strings. This script is running on Debian Linux.

Is there a way to store multiple strings/files directly in memory until I write them all to the disk at a later time?

Comment: If the script is live, you can literally store the data in a variable, in whatever data structure is convenient, as long as the script isn't interrupted, it'll still be there next time it needs to write.

Comment: what operating system? what you're asking either requires operating system interaction (writing files to temporary locations) or re-writing your script to continue running, so the values can be stored in memory as variables before writing to a more permanent file.

Comment: Operating System: Linux, Debian. Adding to question.

Comment: @TheCog The script will run and complete multiple times before I want to write to disk. Instead of writing the results after each run, I want to write those results after multiple runs with the results stored in memory in the meanwhile.

Comment: If you don't mind installing packages you could try to use redis since this fixes everything related for you, https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there are many options for that. One way to do it is to create a temporary string buffer (i.e. container), where you write these strings until disk write is called. If strings are more specific/timestamped or similar, you can use a dictionary to remember their IDs also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a buffer or queue/pipe to put data in them and then whenever suited write into the file pointer and `flush()` it to the hard disk whenever needed.

Comment: You shouldn't write an equally broad answer to go with a broad question.